# Which CSS selector is used when a DragOver event is detected?

Tags: javafx

I am creating a custom `RowFactory` for my `TableView` to accept drag-and-drop files.  I want to update the style of the specific `Row` when an acceptable `DragOver` event is detected.

Using `:hover` obviously won't work because that would apply even if the user is not dragging anything.

The end goal is simply to make it visually clear which row the user is about to drop the items onto.

Is there a selector I can use in my stylesheet to handle this? I could not find anything in the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

---

I can currently work around this by defining my own StyleClass and adding it in the `setOnDragOver()` method:

```
setOnDragOver(event -> {
    // Determine if the dragged items are files
    if (!this.isEmpty() && event.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.LINK);
        this.getStyleClass().add("dragging");
    }
});
```

However, attempting to remove the class when exiting does not seem to work:

```
setOnDragExited(event -> this.getStyleClass().remove("dragging"));
```

**Edit:** I should also clarify that each row may have other styles applied to them (based on several factors) and would want to ADD a style to the row when being dragged over, not replace all the rest)

Comment: would try a custom pseudoClass that's activated in dragOver (or accept) and deactivated in exited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @kleopatra, working with custom PseudoClass can work for you.

```
/**
 * Interface to keep all custom pseudo classes.
 */
public interface Styles{

    /** Dragged pseudo class. */
    public static final PseudoClass DRAGGED_PSEUDOCLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("dragged");
}
```

In your code:

```
setOnDragOver(event -> {
    if (!this.isEmpty() && event.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.LINK);
        this.pseudoClassStateChanged(Styles.DRAGGED_PSEUDOCLASS,true);
    }
});

setOnDragExited(event -> this.pseudoClassStateChanged(Styles.DRAGGED_PSEUDOCLASS,false));
```

In CSS:

```
.table-row-cell:dragged{
  -fx-background-color:$custom-color;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to remove all pseudo classes that have been applied?

Comment: There is method in Node class to get all the current pseudo class states of a node: getPseudoClassStates(). May be you can loop through.. and turn off the states.. something like:
  this.getPseudoClassStates().forEach(pseudoState->this.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoState,false));